# Write \: on a URL

Tags: javascript

I'm using an API that needs a URL like this one:

```
var URL_PARADAS = 'http://datos.santander.es/api/rest/datasets/paradas_bus.json';

function paradas(lat, lon, dist) {
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lon);

  var lat_min = lat - dist;
  var lat_max = lat + dist;

  var lon_min = lon - dist;
  var lon_max = lon + dist;

  var xmlHttp = null;
  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlHttp.open('GET', URL_PARADAS + '?query=wgs84_pos\:lat:{' + lat_min + '%20TO%20' + lat_max + '}'
                                  + '%20AND%20'
                                  + 'wgs84_pos\:long:{' + lon_max + '%20TO%20' + lon_min + '}',
  false);
  xmlHttp.send(null);

  var result = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
  console.log(result);
}
```

[working url](http://datos.santander.es/api/rest/datasets/paradas_bus.json?query=wgs84_pos%5C:lat:%7B42.458545699999995%20TO%2044.458545699999995%7D%20AND%20wgs84_pos%5C:long:%7B-2.8380970999999997%20TO%20-4.8380971%7D)

Without slash: on the URL it won't work, if I use xmlHttp.open(url) it's replaced by : so it doesn't receive anything.

**Edit**: I needed to replace \ to "slash" on this question due to bad output.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: @Niloct Nope, encoded it will be : or %3A, so it doesn't output anything then.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @minitech added. Also I added a working URL and noticed that the encoding function from the page gave me the answer. I tried to encode my self this and didn't work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript string literals [interpret escape sequences](https://es5.github.io/#x7.8.4). If a backslash isn’t followed by a valid escape sequence, it is removed. Escape your backslashes, and they’ll be put in the URL:

```
  xmlHttp.open('GET', URL_PARADAS + '?query=wgs84_pos\\:lat:{' + lat_min + '%20TO%20' + lat_max + '}'
                                  + '%20AND%20'
                                  + 'wgs84_pos\\:long:{' + lon_max + '%20TO%20' + lon_min + '}',
```